# How to store time series data in JSON string form to Apache IoTDB?

Tags: json, apache-iotdb, iotdb

For JSON string kinds of data (which contains multiple time-series values), how should I store this data into Apache IoTDB? Should it be split into different time series, or can it be stored as one string (when queried, the entire JSON is queried as a whole)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your datatype is in JSON string, then it has to be converted to save into Apache IoTDB. You can save it as `string` type in IoTDB, and then converted it to JSON when querying data.